# WebSphere EAR Classloading from Secondary JAR in MANIFEST Classpath

Tags: classpath, ear, websphere-8

My WebSphere 8.5 application has an EAR project containing an MDB project that builds to produce a JAR. That JAR has a class that references classes within a secondary JAR in the EAR that come from a third project.

the manifest for the MDB containing jar (ASyncEJB.jar) is

```
 Manifest-Version: 1.0
 Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.6.2
 Class-Path: ASync.jar 
 lib\aopalliance\aopalliance-1.0.jar 
 lib\asm\asm-3.1.jar 

 etc (more lib references)
```

the manifest for the containing Enterprise project within EAR looks like

```
 Manifest-Version: 1.0
 Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.6.2
 Created-By: abc
 Built-By:   xyz
 Built-Date: September 18 2014
 Implementation-Version: Value_not_provided
```

It looks like the classpath in the ASyncEJB.jar's manifest should enable it to load the class from the secondary ASync.jar.

```
 The structure of the EAR is 

 lib
 META-INF
 ASync.jar
 ASyncEJB.jar
```

The application.xml also withing the META-INF folder with the MANIFEST.MF looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application id="Application_ID" version="6" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd">
 <display-name>AsyncEnterprise</display-name>
 <module id="Module_1381933529290">
    <ejb>ASyncEJB.jar</ejb>
 </module> 
 </application>
```

Why would I get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on a class in  ASync.jar called by a class in ASyncEJB.jar ?

The error is:

```
[22/09/14 15:10:04:285 EDT] 00000065 SharedEJBRunt I   WSVR0057I: EJB jar started: ASyncEJB.jar
[22/09/14 15:10:04:386 EDT] 00000065 BusinessExcep E   CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "initialize" on bean "BeanId(AsyncEnterprise#ASyncEJB.jar#ejbContext, null)". Exception data: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: corporg.core.context.listener.WebContextListener
    at corporg.async.beans.ContextInitilizer.initialize(ContextInitilizer.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InterceptorProxy.invokeInterceptor(InterceptorProxy.java:232)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:559)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.doLifeCycle(InvocationContextImpl.java:273)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.SingletonBeanO.callTransactionalLifecycleInterceptors(SingletonBeanO.java:273)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.SingletonBeanO.initialize(SingletonBeanO.java:404)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.BeanOFactory.create(BeanOFactory.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSHome.createNewBeanO(EJSHome.java:869)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSHome.createSingletonBeanO(EJSHome.java:3981)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.EJBApplicationMetaData.createStartupBeans(EJBApplicationMetaData.java:991)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.EJBApplicationMetaData.startedModule(EJBApplicationMetaData.java:715)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.stateChanged(EJBContainerImpl.java:4866)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.stateChanged(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1120)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectEvent(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1353)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.setState(DeployedModuleImpl.java:248)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.setState(DeployedModuleImpl.java:244)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:642)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:774)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2182)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:994)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: corporg.core.context.listener.WebContextListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:204)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:688)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:667)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:119)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:584)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:584)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: Is "Async.jar" vs "ASync.jar" a typo? Is Async.jar the same as AICIRAsyncEJB.jar? Assuming those are just typos, then ASyncEJB.jar should be able to reference Async.jar. Can you edit your post to add the full ClassNotFoundException stack trace? It might contain clues to the problem.

Comment: Excuse me. Essentially typos. Missed changing names in those places to hide the innocent. Corrected.

Comment: The stack trace suggests the right class loaders are involved, so I'm not sure. You could try enabling `com.ibm.ws.classloader.*=all` trace, restart the application, and look for "ClassGraph > addModule", "ClassGraph 3 local path: ...", "ClassGraph 3 dependency path: ...", "CompoundClass 3 adding ...", and "CompoundClass 3 path=... does not exist" entries in trace.log.  If this is too detailed, you could open a PMR with IBM for additional assistance.

Comment: Thanks. I turned on Class Loader Viewer and added a trace. It gives me details of what it loaded correctly but not anything on failures.

Comment: I widened the trace and it now shows the class not found exception but no extra info indicating why.

Comment: I have written applications that do what you've described, so I know that it can work, but I am out of ideas on what to suggest for you to continue debugging the issue.  I would recommend opening a PMR with IBM so that someone from IBM support can review the trace and determine what has gone wrong.